# Jump to Specific Record/Element of PHP Array on Page Load with Inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have two dynamically driven pages. I am seeking to open the second page so that the image clicked on the first page is at the top of my zIndex as this is how my gallery functions. It is important that the array of the second page remains the same with all associated records in date order.

This is the code I have on the link of the first page which parses information to the second page:

```
echo "<a href=\"artistgallery.php?pageid=".$galleryid."&imageid=".$imageid."\" target=\"_self\"><img src=\"exhibitionimages/".$year."/".$results1->thumbnail."\" class=\"smallimage\"></a>";
```

The script for the second page that creates the gallery which functions by layering blocks with an infinitely increasing z-index is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var z = 10;</script>
$imageid = $_GET['imageid'];
echo "<div id= ".$results1->id." class=\"gallerywrap\">";
                (content in div)
echo "</div>";

echo "<div class=\"gallerymenu\" >";
echo "<a href = \"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(".$results1->id.").style.display='block';document.getElementById(".$results1->id.").style.zIndex = z++;\" class=\"subheading\">$year</a>";
echo "</div>";
```

Currently the `$imageid` above is not called.  The following are variations of the script I have alternated in placing on the gallery menu div and the gallerywrap div:

```
    onload=\"id=".$imageid."\"

    window.onload=document.getElementById.if("$results1->id"=="$imageid").style.display='block';document.getElementById.if("$results1->id"=="$imageid").style.zIndex = z++;

    onload=\"linkedImage(".$results1->id."=".$imageid.").style.zIndex = z++; \"


    onload=\"document.getElementById.if(".$results1->id."==".$imageid.").style.display='block'=".$imageid.";document.getElementById.if(".$results1->id."==".$imageid.").style.zIndex = z++'=".$imageid.";\"
```

My problem is where to place it and what code will function. Ultimately I am trying to say: "if `results1->id` == `$imageid`, then up the z-index for that record so it sits on top when the page loads".

I have also dabbled with data_seek on the php end though with not much success.

Comment: Adding an `onload` to an anchor isn't going to do much, as it'll never be fired.

Comment: I have come to that conclusion, what do you suggest will enable the fire? do i need to parse the event over the browser? or what would i need to call the event on the second page? Thanks!

Comment: Would the answer lie with data_seek with the mysqli on the second page as the image id goes over the browser? I tried a few iterations of that also though could not get it working! @Niels Keurentjes

Comment: You need to understand that events are specified by the standards as belonging to certain DOM elements. Adding a random event to an element doesn't magically tell the browser how to trigger it. An `onload` belongs on iframes and on body elements. To have some code trigger on the new page, you need to add it to the new page in a place that will trigger.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes i have edited the question!